# How to not repeat myself when assigning several properties

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an event listener with the parameter of the callback function `event`, assigned to an element. Is there any way how I could select that element's 5th parent without needing to write down this code?

```
event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Comment: I didn't ask for this

Comment: That is how you can do it without repeating yourself. You asked for that. ;)

Comment: Find something unique about the element's 5th parent and use that to target it. Targeting "the 5th parent" will break your code as soon as someone else comes along an restructures the HTML. It is a very brittle method of programming.

Comment: Ohhh.. You are right.. Sorry

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought you answered in the actual answers section and only pasted a link, and I didn't pay close attention because I had the pre-made thought that it was just for the score ;p @epascarello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, there are a few ways you can achieve this.

I. The JQuery Method:

```
$('#element1').parents().eq(5);
```

II. Raw Javascript

```
Function returnNthParent(n, element) 
{
 parent = element;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
       parent = parent.parentNode;
    }
 return parent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no nth parent method so you have to either do a bunch of parentNode's or use [closest(selector)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) which will walk the DOM tree until it finds a match. So you find something unique about it and use that

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener("input", function(evt) {
  const row = evt.target.closest('.row');
  console.log(row);
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the exact number of the parent elements chain you need to go through, then you may implement simple helper

```js
const takeParent = (target, count) => {
  while (--count >= 0) {
    if (target === document) {
      break;
    }
    target = target.parentNode;
  }
  return target;
};

takeParent(myElement, 5); // give 5th parent of myElement or "document" if there are less than 5 parents
```